# Matlab Eval function keeps returning information to command window

Tags: matlab, eval, command-window

A part of my script consists of the following two codes, but for some reason the `eval` function is still returning information to the command window. As you can see I use a semicolon at the end of the lines but I'm guessing it is not placed right.

```
eval(['Norm_Accelerance' num2str(i0) ' = (Interp_accelerance-min(Interp_accelerance))/(max(Interp_accelerance)-min(Interp_accelerance));']);


eval(['Average_Norm_Accelerance = Average_Norm_Accelerance + Norm_Accelerance' num2str(i);]);
```

Comment: Also, don't use `eval`.  Use arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an `eval` statement, you need the semi-colon *in the string*. Your first line has this so that one should not be printing any values. The second one is missing that trailing semi-colon. You have one there, it's just a semi-colon and not a *string* containing a semi-colon. The second line should instead look like this:

```
eval(['Average_Norm_Accelerance = Average_Norm_Accelerance + Norm_Accelerance' num2str(i) ';']);
```

More importantly, [**do not use `eval`. Even The Mathworks says it's a bad idea.**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html)